# PHP echo MySQL value in If/Else

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP echo value that displays a value from a MySQL database like this:

```
<?php echo($row_WADAHTG_TechProps["EmpType"]); ?>
```

I need to construct an if/else with this value but am getting a syntax error no matter how I try to arrange this:

```
<?php
if (echo($row_WADAHTG_TechProps["EmpType"]) = "6001") {
  echo "Have a good day!";
} else {
  echo "Have a good night!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try that:

```
 <?php
      if ($row_WADAHTG_TechProps["EmpType"] == "6001") {
             echo "Have a good day!";
      } else {
             echo "Have a good night!";
      }
 ?>
```

Comment: +1, but why aren't you using the strict comparison operator (i.e ===)?

Comment: @JackWilliam === is used for checking the equality as well as type.

Comment: 6001 can maybe a integer or string . so it will be true in both. but with === it will just accept same type.

Comment: You're right, but I presumed he was expecting it as a string. It depends on the OP's app.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $row_WADAHTG_TechProps["EmpType"] == "6001") {
   echo "Have a good day!";
 } else {
   echo "Have a good night!";
 }
```

Careful with the single '=' sign in the if statement as that is an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
<?php
    if ($row_WADAHTG_TechProps["EmpType"] == "6001") {
        echo "Have a good day!";
    } else {
        echo "Have a good night!";
    }
?>
```

you have to compare a value with `==`or `===` (if you also want to compare the type)

Answer (score 1):

### I use shorthand ternary operators for if/else conditions

```
($row_WADAHTG_TechProps["EmpType"] === "6001" ? echo "Yes" : echo "No");
```

Notice I'm strictly comparing `$row_WADAHTG_TechProps["EmpType"]` to "6001" as strings, therefore if either of them are integers, the condition will `echo "No"`.